# Projecting the Order in which Different Objects with Values that Decrement Over Time Reach Zero

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I'm fairly certain that there's a name for exactly what I'm trying to do here, but I'm not sure what is exactly, so if this looks extremely familiar, feel free to tell me exactly what I should be looking up!

Say I have a list of objects with a value that starts at 100 and decrements to 0 overtime. These objects could be defined as such:

```cs
public struct OrderableObject
{
   float DecrementRate; // Some arbitrary number
   float StartValue; // 100
   float CurrentValue; // Initially same as StartValue
}
```

And I could have a list of instances of these objects so that

```cs
OrderableObject objectA = new OrderableObject() { DecrementRate = 1.0f, StartValue = 100.0f, CurrentValue = 100.0f };
OrderableObject objectB = new OrderableObject() { DecrementRate = 1.0f, StartValue = 100.0f, CurrentValue = 100.0f };
OrderableObject objectC = new OrderableObject() { DecrementRate = 1.0f, StartValue = 100.0f, CurrentValue = 100.0f };
OrderableObject objectD = new OrderableObject() { DecrementRate = 3.0f, StartValue = 100.0f, CurrentValue = 100.0f };
OrderableObject objectE = new OrderableObject() { DecrementRate = 0.5f, StartValue = 100.0f, CurrentValue = 100.0f };
OrderableObject objectF = new OrderableObject() { DecrementRate = 1.0f, StartValue = 100.0f, CurrentValue = 100.0f };

var orderableObjects = new List<OrderableObject>()
{
    objectA, objectB, objectC, objectD, objectE, objectF
};
```

I'd like to be able to run a function wherein I pass in an `int`projectionLength, as well as my list of `orderableObjects` and it returns a list of the projected order in which each of the above objects reaches `0` for a number of entries matching `projectionLength`.  When an object reaches `0`, it should reset to `100`, so in the case of `objectD` with a high `DecrementRate` of `3.0`, I'd want to see it appear in the list multiple consecutive times to reflect the fact that its `CurrentValue` will hit `0` more frequently than the other entries.  On that same token, there'd be "loops" wherein `objectE` won't even appear since all other entries will decrement to `0` at least twice before it has a chance to do so even once.

So an example output with a `projectionLength` of `15` might look something like:

```cs
[objectD, objectD, objectA, objectB, objectC, objectD, objectF, objectD, objectD, objectA, objectB, objectC, objectD, objectE, objectF]
```

(I typed this in manually so hopefully I haven't made my goal confusing by getting it wrong)

I know how I could accomplish the same thing by running a time simulation with a fixed timestep, but I figured it was worth asking if there's a more "mathematical" (and likely more efficient) way of achieving the same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption:**

1. All objects decrement at the same time.
2. The fastest object will be the object with the highest DecrementRate.
3. The slowest object will be the object with the lowest DecrementRate.
4. Ties are resolved by random.
5. The number of decrements an object will take to reach 0 is its start divided by its rate.
6. The total amount of time the task will take is equal to the slowest objects total time.

**Idea:**

Essentially, each object is just a fraction...

- Each object will follow a specific fractional pattern as it decrements, and it will follow this fractional series for the total amount of time.
- Therefore, we just need to find the fractional series of each object, and sort the results in the order of those fractional values which are equal to the decrements the objects takes.

**Example:**

```
Obj A

    Rate = 5
    Start = 100
    decrements_to_0 = 100 / 5 = 20

Obj B

    Rate = 10
    Start = 100
    decrements_to_0 = 100 / 10 = 10

Obj C

    Rate = 2
    Start = 100
    decrements_to_0 = 100 / 2 = 50 <--- max number of decrements ---
                                                                   |
         ----------------------------------------------------------
        |
        V  divide each object's decrements by the total decrements
A: 20 / 50 = 0.4, 0.8
B: 10 / 50 = 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0
C: 50 / 50 = 1.0

0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0 // fractions in order
B  , A  , B  , B  , A  , B  , B  , C   // results
```

**Solution:**

https://jsfiddle.net/r6osaL0b/1/

```
// Utility functions
function decrements_to_0(obj) { return obj.start / obj.rate; } // same thing as time, kinda like miles / miles_per_hour = hours

function fractional_series(numerator, denominator) { 
    return (new Array(Math.trunc(denominator/numerator))).fill(undefined).map((_, i) => ((i + 1) * numerator)/denominator);
}

// Setup our OrderableObjects 
var OrderableObject = function (name, rate, start) { return {name: name, rate: rate, start: start}; }
var list = [
    OrderableObject("A", 1,100),
    OrderableObject("B", 1,100),
    OrderableObject("C", 1,100),
    OrderableObject("D", 3,100),
    OrderableObject("E", 0.5,100),
    OrderableObject("F", 1,100)
];

// Get each objects decrements
var decrements_list = list.map((obj) => { return {obj: obj, decrements: decrements_to_0(obj)}; });

// Get the max decrements, which belogns to our slowest object
var max_decrements = decrements_list.sort((obj1, obj2) => { return obj2.decrements - obj1.decrements; })[0].decrements;

// Get the fractional series corresponding to each object
var fractions_list = decrements_list.map((d_obj) => {
    return fractional_series(d_obj.decrements, max_decrements).map((fraction) => { return {obj: d_obj.obj, value: fraction}; });
})
.flat() // flatten the fractions into a single array
.sort((obj1, obj2) => { return obj1.value - obj2.value; }); // sort them in order

var results = fractions_list.map((f_obj) => { return f_obj.obj.name; }); // we only need the name of the orderable objects for the results

console.log(results); // D,D,D,A,B,C,F,D,D,D,E,A,B,C,F
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for a well-explained and simple solution!